# Compilers that required # on the first column?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, kernighan-and-ritchie

Were there widely used pre-ANSI C compilers<sup>†</sup> that required the `#` to be on the first column?

> <sub>† I would accept any compiler on [this list](https://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml). If I can find mention of it in the comp.lang.c Usenet newsgroup in a post dated before 1995, I would accept it.</sub>

K&R C did not specify whether whitespace was permitted before the `#`. From the original *The C Programming Language*, §12¶1 of the "C Reference Manual" in Appendix A:

> The C compiler contains a preprocessor capable of macro substitution, conditional compilation, and inclusion of named files. Lines beginning with `#` communicate with this preprocessor.

Thus, whether or not whitespace was permitted to precede the `#` was unspecified. This would mean a pre-ANSI compiler could fail to compile a program if the directive did not begin on the first column.

In ISO C (and in ANSI C before that), the C preprocessing directives were explicitly permitted to be prefixed with whitespace. In ANSI C (C-89):

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens that begins with a `#` preprocessing token that is either the
>   first character in the source file (optionally after white space
>   containing no new-line characters) or that follows white space
>   containing at least one new-line character, and is ended by the next
>   new-line character.

ISO C.2011 has similar language, but is clarified even further:

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the
>   following constraints: The first token in the sequence is a `#` preprocessing token that (at
>   the start of translation phase 4) is either the first character in the source file (optionally
>   after white space containing no new-line characters) or that follows white space
>   containing at least one new-line character. The last token in the sequence is the first newline
>   character that follows the first token in the sequence.<sup>165)</sup> A new-line character ends
>   the preprocessing directive even if it occurs within what would otherwise be an invocation of a function-like macro.
>   <sub>165) Thus, preprocessing directives are commonly called ‘‘lines’’. These ‘‘lines’’ have no other syntactic
>   significance, as all white space is equivalent except in certain situations during preprocessing (see the
>   `#` character string literal creation operator in 6.10.3.2, for example).</sub>

Comment: Someone did mention that in a comment to a recent question, but MSVC does not require the `#` of `#include` to be in the first column.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Right, this is a question about old C compilers before ANSI required preprocessors to allow whitespace to precede the `#`.

Comment: What does "widely used" mean in the context of pre-ansi C?

Comment: @rici: Clarified this point in the question.

Comment: @rici: From my recollection, there were a few very popular C compilers pre-ANSI. There is of course the original Ken Thompson's C compiler. There is the original portable C compiler (pcc) by Stephen Johnson. I had an old SuperPET that supported the C language, but I am not sure of its origins. Most C compilers coming out of the early 90s vendors still supported pre-ANSI C, because most C software source was written in that style.

Comment: @rici: I did a little research on the SuperPET's C support. It probably originated from Watcom's C, since Watcom had provided the software for the other languages the SuperPET supported.

Comment: TIL that whitespace is permitted before the hash:)

Comment: Jxh, my rather oblique point was that pre ANSI C was not exactly mainstream, so "widely popular" has to be interpreted relatively. I did write a C program for some dec-11 at some point, but where I was, it was generally considered to be marginal, and a little wierd. Today, of course, it is no longer marginal. :-) I carried the habit of putting the # in the first column for many years, but I honestly can't remember if that was because some compiler told me to. These days, I indent the #.

Comment: @rici: But, it was probably based on pcc, though, right? I seem to recall a lot of systems retargeted pcc's backend, until GCC became popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

I remember writing things like

```
#if foo
    /* ... */
#else
#if bar
    /* ... */
#else
 #error "neither foo nor bar specified"
#endif
#endif
```

so that the various pre-ANSI compilers that I once used wouldn't complain about "unrecognized preprocessor directive '#error'".  This would have been with Ritchie's original cc for the pdp11, or pcc (the "portable C compiler" which, IIRC, was the basis for the Vax cc of the 80's or so).  Both of those compilers -- more accurately, the preprocessor used with both of those compilers -- definitely required the `#` to be in the first column.  (Actually, although those compilers were very different, they might both have used different variants of basically the same preprocessor, which was always a separate program in those days.)

Comment: I might edit this answer in the future to add a Changelog entry if I can find it when pcc was brought up to full ANSI C compliance (including supporting whitespace before the `#`).